# Validate simple optional inputs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have 3 inputs and a checkbox.

The first 2 inputs are required and the date is only required if the checkbox is not checked.

The problem is that I want to disable the submit button if either the first 2 inputs are not valid and I need somehow to check if the checkbox is not checked, i need to validate the date, if it's checked, then I dont need the date.

How do I do that?

```html
<tr>
  <td><b>NEUE IBAN</b> <i class="required-asterix">*</i></td>
  <td class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><span><b>DE</b></span></span>
      <input validator="/^(\d *){20}$/" id="newIban" ng-keyup="vm.checkIBAN();" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="fehlerhafte IBAN-Eingabe" ng-model="vm.NewReferenceAccount.newReferenceNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert a new IBAN" required>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>KONTOINHABER</b> <i class="required-asterix">*</i></td>
  <td class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input validator="/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/" validator-error="fehlerhafte KONTOINHABER-Eingabe" validator-invoke="watch" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.NewReferenceAccount.newAccountNameOwner" placeholder="Insert a new Account owner " required>
    </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>GÜLTIG ab</b> <i class="required-asterix">*</i></td>
  <td>
    <input uib-tooltip="Check if it's current date" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.NewReferenceAccount.isNotFutureDate" ng-init="vm.NewReferenceAccount.isNotFutureDate = true" />

    <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
      <date-picker ng-model="vm.NewReferenceAccount.changeDate" uib-tooltip="Select the Change Date" ng-readonly="vm.NewReferenceAccount.isNotFutureDate" date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" date-parser-format="DD-MM-YYYY" required />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>


  <button type="button" ng-disabled="??????????????????" ng-click="vm.acceptTicket();" uib-tooltip="Accept the ticket" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-success">Weiter&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `oninput` event to validate the first to fields while the user is typing in them and disable/enable the button accordingly. You can find more on this event, and how to use it, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp).

For the checkbox you can use the `onchange` event so you know when the user clicks selects/deselects it. More on the `onchange`  event, and usage examples, can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)